# Genshi and Python Generators (yield)

Tags: python, generator, genshi

How do I create/call a python generator in Genshi? Is that even possible?

For example, (and no i'm not looking for an alternate solution to this problem, of which there are many, including enumerate on the for each, etc):

```
 <?python
  """ a bunch of other code ... """
  def bg_color_gen():
    """ Alternate background color every call """
    while 1:
      yield "#FFFFFF"
      yield "#EBEBEB"
  ?>
```

And then calling this function:

```
  <fo:block background-color="${bg_color_gen()}">First entry</fo:block>
  <fo:block background-color="${bg_color_gen()}">Second entry</fo:block>
  <fo:block background-color="${bg_color_gen()}">Third entry</fo:block>
```

This has nothing to do with my < fo:block >, which you could replace with < div >. It is not an FO question but a Genshi question.
I'm guessing Genshi doesn't recognize the 'yield' and runs 'while 1' ad-infinitum?

Also, I do realize I could use a global to keep track of a counter, and then call

```
 counter++
 if counter%yieldCount==0: return "#FFFFFFF"
 elif counter%yieldCount==1: return "#EBEBEB"
```

But this is not a generator and gets ugly very quickly!

Clarification:
Another way to ask this question: how would you code

```
def fib():
    a,b = 0,1
    while True:
        yield a
        b = a+b
        yield b
        a = a+b
```

Which would then be called in the sentence "The first number is $fib(), the second is $fib(), the third is $fib(), and so on."

================================================

Updated full solution based on accepted answer:

```
<?python
def fib_generator():
    a,b = 0,1
    while True:
        yield a
        b = a+b
        yield b
        a = a+b
fib = fib_generator()
?>


The first number is ${next(fib)}, 
the second is ${next(fib)},
the third is ${next(fib)}, and so on.
```

Comment: What is used in place of "First", "Second" and "Third" entry? Is that dynamic or is that really the kind of text you'll be using?

Comment: It shouldn't matter for this question. But it can be exactly like this or inside a for loop that prints a bunch of rows, where some of them have their own background-color and we don't want to interrupt/reset the alternating colors.
Basically, the only question here is how do i get generators.

...How about ${fibonnaci()} ${fibonnaci()} ${fibonnaci()} for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the structure of your content, I would suggest the following:

```
<fo:block py:for="i, entry in entries"
          background-color="${'#FFFFFF' if i % 2 else '#EBEBEB'}">
  ${entry}
</fo:block>
```

However if you truly want to use a generator then you could just evaluate using Python's native `next()`

```
<py:with vars="color=bg_color_gen();">
  <fo:block background-color="${next(color)}">
</py:with>
```

Comment: The reason your first response wouldn't work is that i'm inside a for loop already and some entries don't get displayed while others do. Your second solution however answers my question succinctly!

Comment: OK NP, I'm willing to be convinced but I'd suggest that it's almost always possible to loop using a combination of my first suggestion in addition to `py:if` and `py:strip`. Genshi can be pretty powerful if you make use of all of it's features :)

Answer (score 1):

You would want to declare the generator first and then call `next` on it to get a `yield`ed color.

In this case you are passing three different instances of the generator created by calling `bg_color_gen()` ie)

```
# this creates a generator
>>> bg_color_gen()
<generator object bg_color_gen at 0x02B21A30>
>>> bgcg = bg_color_gen()
# this gets values
>>> next(bgcg)
'#FFFFFF'
>>> next(bgcg)
'#EBEBEB'
>>> next(bgcg)
'#FFFFFF'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it shows me where I was wrong. I accepted the other answer because it tells me how to do it exactly, but your response explains the why of it (which to me is just as important), which is so simple!

Comment: @Pierre-Francoys Brousseau not a problem.